# Start Drag On Click (Angular draggable droppable)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I want to start the dragging when clicked on the draggable element. I am using https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-draggable-droppable

```
<div mwlDraggable (click)="startDrag()"></div>
```

Comment: it doesn't look like that module supports click-toggled drag and drop.  it's optimized for mouse and mobile.  if you look into the code you can see where the event listeners are set up; you could conceivably fork and modify it yourself to add the desired functionality.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have some missing data inside of your `<div>`. Please consult: https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-draggable-droppable/blob/master/projects/angular-draggable-droppable/src/lib/draggable.directive.ts#L70

The demo the owner of the repo has posted is of use as well: https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-draggable-droppable/blob/master/src/demo/demo.component.html#L4

Comment: OP is asking for specific functionality, not how to use the tool in general.  answer does not address the OPs question